# Can one make a Chanukas Habayis at any point in time?

Tags: minhag, home-house

*The Radak (Shorashim, חנך) writes that "it is a minhag to have a meal and happiness at the first eating that they eat in the new house".* The above is quoted as part of an answer to a question previously posted on MY regarding Chanukas Habayis.

My question is what happens if the first meal has already passed? Is there still an inyan of making a Chanukas Habayis at a later point in time or if one misses the first meal he is no longer fufilling the Minhag of making a Chanukas Habayis ?

Comment: If someone would like to make the Radak I quoted into a link feel free to do that.

Comment: Note that you dont quote Radak as saying that there is an "inyan" just that some people do something.

Comment: In my experience people don't do it for the first meal. So the minhag clearly has changed.

Comment: There seems to be a nuance in the term "chanukat habayit" as to whether it means "dedication" or "inauguration". I used Google translate on the word "Chanukah" and both definitions appear. So, if it really means "inauguration", then, well, after the first meal, the time has passed. I'm leaning towards that definition, since the gifts that the tribes gave at the "Chanukat Hamizbe'ach" were given at its inauguration. But, that's my analysis of it, here - no source.

Comment: Presumably the "inyan" is hakarat hatov. If that is the case, then presumably whenever he does so, he is fulfilling this.

Comment: @DanF I'm not disagreeing with you, but what about the "chanukat habayit" after the story of Chanuka? Is that considered an inauguration?

Comment: @Ploni That would probably be considered an "inauguration" as well. Even though th eBet Hamikdash had been there all along, it was unusable for a long time. So, in a sense, it was considered (in terms of daily service, etc.) as if it wasn't there. After cleaning it and making it usable, they did an inaugural the first time they were able to re-use it.